# Git diff <merge commit> shows changed files from previous commits

Tags: git, merge, git-diff

```
mergeA
commitA
commitB
commitC
commitD
```

Where commitA only contained changes already made in commitD

`git diff mergeA..commitB`

Shows nothing, but

`git diff mergeA^..mergeA`

shows all changes made in commits B-C as changes made in mergeA

I don't understand what's happening here; was a push made at commitA, then pull, then merge & push?

Comment: `gitk --all` should give you a graphical representation of this to better understand what is going on.

Comment: `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, so "push, then pull, then merge" is redundant. It is, however, important to view the graph here (`git log --oneline --graph`, e.g., or use `gitk` as @J.Titus suggested) so that one can tell what commit `mergeA^` names. Note that `mergeA^` is the *first* parent of the merge, which might be `commitB` here; `mergeA^2` is the *second* parent of the merge, which might be `commitA` here, perhaps.

Comment: (Slight correction to my "might be" comment: if `git diff mergeA commitB` shows nothing, and `git diff mergeA^ mergeA` shows B+C, probably `mergeA^` is `commitA`. In any case actually seeing the graph should clear this up quickly.)

Comment: Yup, the graph has clarified what's going on -- thanks a lot guys. I think the (small) changes in commitD were individually made by two people, one continuing on to C, B, A and the other later merging in the same D changes to the C, B, A commit.